# PHP Checkbox from db, unchecked after submit

Tags: php, checkbox

I have this code. I need that all the checkbox (taken by database) that I choose remain checked even after submitting the page.How can I do that?

```
?>
<?php
function connetti(){
$conn=mysql_connect("localhost","user","pass");
mysql_select_db('colours');
return $conn;
}
?>
<html>
<head>
<title>Scelta colori</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Scelta colori</h1>
    <h1>Benvenuto <?php echo $_SESSION['user']; ?></h1><br>
    <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post">
        <?php
            $conn=connetti();
            $sql="SELECT tonalita FROM colori";
            $risultato=mysql_query($sql);
            while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($risultato)){
            $valore=$row['tonalita'];
            echo('<input type="checkbox"  value="'.$valore.'" name="colori[]">'.$valore.'</input><br>');  
                    }
            mysql_free_result($risultato);
            mysql_close($conn);
        ?>


        <input type="submit" value="Invia">
        <input type="reset" value="Annulla">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does this actually submit to the database?

Comment: no, i take values from db. My only problem is that checkbox are not checked after submit. An example, if i check the firts color(red) when i click submit i have the color red unckecked.

Comment: Yes, I understand what you're doing. Where is the code for submitting to the database? It should be on this page, yes? If the values are submitted to the database they will be loaded when the page refreshes. So everything should work if you successfully submit the values to the database. Or do you not wish to submit them to the db?

Comment: i don't want to submit to the db, i want to see on the same page, like sticky form.

Comment: Ahhh, then UnskilledFreak's answer with my last fix/comment to it should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

u can use, after submitting the form, the `$_POST` vars and check it with `$valore`

```
<?php

echo('<input type="checkbox"  value="'.$valore.'" name="colori['.$valore.']"'.((isset($_POST["colori"][$valore])&&$_POST["colori"][$valore]==$valore)?' checked="checked"':"").'>'.$valore.'</input><br>');  

?>
```

untestet but should work

**edit: got the error on the name-attr and fixed issue on not settet index. testet on php5**

Comment: She doesn't need to use the post variables if what she's submitting actually reaches the database. The page will load again and read them from the db.

Comment: u r right if it stores in the same table/loads query, but if not and this is only an "update-form", this is the easiest way i gues

Comment: @UnskilledFreak You can remove the parentheses after the `echo` and use commas to separate your ternary statement from the echo parts that should execute regardless of what the ternary statement evaluates to. Because this way PHP will interpret your echo statement improperly. Change to this: `echo '<input type="checkbox" value="'.$valore.'" name="colori['.$valore.']"' , ((isset($_POST["colori"][$valore]) && $_POST["colori"][$valore] == $valore) ? ' checked="checked"' : "" , '>'.$valore.'</input><br>';` Notice the commas, they're important.

Comment: thanks for this information, i wrote myself like yours, but do it like this cause the question owner used it. but is it obsolete/deprecated to use echo like print as function?

Comment: there is a ) less at the end of isset

Comment: commas wont work for me too, this is working for me: `echo '<input type="checkbox"  value="'.$valore.'" name="colori['.$valore.']"'.((isset($_POST["colori"][$valore])&&$_POST["colori"][$valore]==$valore)?' checked="checked"':"").'>'.$valore.'</input><br>';`

Comment: @UnskilledFreak add ) at the end of isset ((isset($_POST["colori"][$valore]) && $_POST["colori"][$valore] == $valore))

Comment: u r right, u also can add the missing ) to ` : "" ) , '>'` to close the shortif itself